# Android Studio - Sobre Scrollview

Tags: android

Eu tenho uma tela normal com textview apenas. E no final tem um Videoview. A scrollview fuciona normalmente, consigo girar para cima e para baixo. O problema é que quando eu inicio a activity, em vez de começar no topo da tela, ele já começa em cima do videoview. Ja tentei focusable = false e não foi. Abaixo o meu XML:

```
>


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"


    >



<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Tipos de Dados"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:id="@+id/txt_titulo1"
    android:textSize="18dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    />



<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="É a forma de como serão classificas as informações que serão inseridas no banco de dados. Nesta capítulos, veremos os tipos de dados mais comuns e mais utilizados."
    android:id="@+id/txt_titulo2"
    android:textSize="18dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txt_titulo1"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"

    />


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Numérico"
    android:id="@+id/txt_titulo3"
    android:textSize="18dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txt_titulo2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    />



    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="SMALLINT: número inteiro pequeno;"

        android:id="@+id/txt_titulo5"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"

        android:layout_below="@+id/txt_titulo4"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="São os dados que serão utilizados para armazenar números, sendo eles inteiros ou decimais. Exemplos:"
        android:id="@+id/txt_titulo4"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"

        android:layout_below="@+id/txt_titulo3"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="INT: Número inteiro de tamanho comum."
        android:id="@+id/txt_titulo6"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txt_titulo5"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"


        />


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="MEDIUMINT: número inteiro de tamanho médio."
        android:id="@+id/txt_titulo7"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txt_titulo6"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"


        />


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="BIGINT: número inteiro de tamanho grande;"
        android:id="@+id/txt_titulo8"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txt_titulo7"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"


        />


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Float: Número pequeno em vírgula flutuante de precisão simples."
        android:id="@+id/txt_titulo9"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txt_titulo8"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"

        />


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Strings"
        android:id="@+id/txt_titulo10"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txt_titulo9"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="São cadeias de caracteres, podendo ser números e letras."
        android:id="@+id/txt_titulo11"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"

        android:layout_below="@+id/txt_titulo10"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        />


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Char(n): Armazena um texto de longitude fixa. Onde fica o '(n)', será a quantidade de caracteres a serem armazenados. Ex: Char(30). "
        android:id="@+id/txt_titulo12"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"

        android:layout_below="@+id/txt_titulo11"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        />


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Varchar(n): Armazena um texto de longitude variável. "
        android:id="@+id/txt_titulo13"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"

        android:layout_below="@+id/txt_titulo12"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Data"
        android:id="@+id/txt_titulo14"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txt_titulo13"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        />


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Serve para armazenar dados relacio- nados as datas."
        android:id="@+id/txt_titulo15"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"

        android:layout_below="@+id/txt_titulo14"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        />


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Date: Armazena uma data. Formato de armazenamento é de ano-mes-dia."
        android:id="@+id/txt_titulo16"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"

        android:layout_below="@+id/txt_titulo15"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"

        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        />


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="DateTime: Combinação de data e hora. Formato de armazenamento é de ano-mes-dia horas:minutos: segundos;"
        android:id="@+id/txt_titulo17"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"

        android:layout_below="@+id/txt_titulo16"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"

        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        />


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Time: Armazena uma hora. Formato de armazenamento é ‘HH:MM:SS’;"
        android:id="@+id/txt_titulo18"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txt_titulo17"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txt_titulo18"
        android:text="Assistir Resumo"
        android:onClick="videoplay"
        android:id="@+id/botao_video" />

    <VideoView
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/botao_video"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        tools:visibility="invisible"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:id="@+id/videoView" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

o que começa em cima do `<VideoView>` o `<ScrollView>`? Se é isto você precisa separar os componentes para que um fique abaixo do outro usando o `RelativeLayout` e o `android:layout_below="@id/id"` para que o componente fique *abaixo*. Tentei fazer rapidinho aqui, teste pra ver se é isso que você queria desenvolver:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linear1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName"
                    android:text="Name" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editText2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName"
                    android:text="Name2" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editText3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName"
                    android:text="Name3" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editText4"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName"
                    android:text="Name4" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editText5"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName"
                    android:text="Name5" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editText6"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName"
                    android:text="Name6" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editText7"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName"
                    android:text="Name7" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editText8"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName"
                    android:text="Name8" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editText9"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName"
                    android:text="Name9" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editText10"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName"
                    android:text="Name10" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/linear1"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <VideoView
                android:id="@+id/video"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Valeus ai pela dica . obrigado

Comment: Por nada! Se é a resposta esperada marque ela como correta por favor. Obrigado